# Show $[F(\alpha):F]$ is even with a map of the Galois group is given.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Suppose $F(\alpha)/F$ is Galois extension, $\alpha \notin F$, and there exists $f$ in $\operatorname{Gal}(F(\alpha)/F)$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha^{-1}$. Show $[F(\alpha):F]$ is even.

Ok, I know $F(\alpha)= \{a_0+\alpha a_1 \mid a_i\in F\}$ and since roots are mapped to roots in galois extensions, $a^{-1}$ is also a root. Am I supposed to get a relation with this pair of roots and generalize to the degree? Any help is welcomed.

Comment: What can you say about $f\circ f$?

Comment: The $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ in the expression $$F(\alpha)= \{a_0+\alpha a_1 \mid a_i\in F\}$$ should not be excluded from MathJax. See my edit to the question.

Answer (score 3):

First, prove for yourself that $f \circ f$ is the identity automorphism on $F(\alpha)$.  Why will this fix *everything* in $F(\alpha)$ and not just $\alpha$?  What does this say about the element $f$ in the group $\text{Gal}(F(a)/F) \ $?  Now think about the various results from early on in group theory; what can we say about $| \text{Gal}(F(a)/F) |$?

Lastly, how is the order of a finite Galois group related to degrees of field extensions?